# Log Into Exchange Mailbox Via PHP?

Tags: php, automation, exchange-server

I am writing a script to perform some tasks, but I am stuck when it comes to logging into my exchange mailbox in order to strip a line out of a mail in the inbox for use. (I'm quite new to this stuff..)

Literally, all i know is:
- The mailbox is exchange 
- I need to log into it 
- It needs to be automated.

I will then need to parse the mail to pull the single line out and match the contents of that line to a database, so any pointers toward that would be great too.

Thanks in advance, any input is much appreciated.

EDIT: I've had a look around google, and cannot seem to find anything that will help me, or that I understand (Like i say, i'm a new to this stuff.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your mailbox is hosted in Office 365, then you can use the Mail API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations). If it's not on Office 365, you could use Exchange Web Services (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn600185(v=exchg.150).aspx).